# How to download image from browser asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Is there any way i can download image using asp.net

I want to dialog box opened to save it

Thanks

Comment: Why all the votes to close? The question could be better, but seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: A touch of English language snobbery and/or racism?

Comment: @5arx, racism is a bit strong.  English language snobbery fits though.

Answer (score 3):

Create a link to a download page like this:

```
Download.aspx?Image=whatever.jpg
```

and then in Download.aspx set the content headers:

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=whatever.jpg");
```

The browser will display a save dialog instead of displaying it.